# Wp-admin is giving me an error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.". I do have access to the wp-admin besides the dashboard itself

Tags: wp-admin, errors, dashboard

When I insert example.com/wp-admin/ I get an error "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.".  But the rest of wp-admin I can access, for example:
 example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php.

These are the steps I took in order to solve the issue:

1. I disabled my plugins and theme.
2. Reinstalled core WordPress files.
3. I tried to debug but I could not find any errors.

What else is there to do?

Comment: clear browser cache and login again. then save permalinks